# What can i find in a spectrogram?

Tags: spectrogram

What information can i read from this spectrogram? I have 2 signals, the first one a sine and the second one a sine with noise
[image]

Comment: Seriously, you need to give **a lot** more background on your questions. None of your questions are detailed enough to give you good answers. They are mostly "what can I see here" questions, and really, one can't see anything without knowing what one looks at. So, explain your whole problem, give context, ask a complete question rather than just describing the proverbial tip of the iceberg. "What can **I** find ..": we can't tell *you* what **you** can find. You're not telling us what *you* are looking at. Signals are meaningful **only in a specific context**.

Answer (score 1):

without the context of an application, very little.

We use STFT analysis to understand the physics, or physiology, or behaviors of signal sources.

Your question has no context to make an informative inference

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the horizontal axis is time and vertical is frequency, I am going to associate **A** and **B** with the top and bottom specgram, respectively.  Both seems to be ringing at the tone between 0.4 and 1.2 in time.

If the peaks are in red, it looks like A and B have single tones in and around the same frequency bins.  From the green background, the bottom specgram looks to have a higher noise floor across all the time samples.  This is consistent with what you mentioned about B has noise added.

Something else may be of interest is that A seems to have a dip around 0.8 in time.  This can be seen in the side lobes.